# mapView is not changing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I used google map v2. There is no error in logcat.

method for initializing map;

```
public class GoogleMapFragment extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                                                       GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                                                       LocationListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private Location location;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String provider;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private MapFragment mMapFragment;
private LatLng latLang;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_map);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

     mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

    try {

        initializeLocation();

        initializeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.configuration, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initializeLocation(){

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();


    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location); 
    }
}

private void initializeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);         

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 14f)); 

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);


        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeLocation();
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // If the client is connected
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override     
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();    
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    String msg = "Updated Location: " + "\n" +
            Double.toString(latitude) + "\n" +
            Double.toString(longitude);

    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

When I debug, lat and long values are correct. but even I change map type, I always get this map. **Movecamera, addMarker, setMapType is not working..** And no error found in logcat.

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste your entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the code of change location and move map camera in location changed method

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

         latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();       
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);// Creating a LatLng object for the current location
         googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); // Showing the current location in Google Map
         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }
```